# Performance at Work

Tags: statistics, systems-of-equations

So, at work we have a system of getting employee ratings. Customers fill out surveys, and we get scores. Here's how it works:

$$\text{If I get a score of } 5,\text{it counts as } 100 \text{ points}$$
$$\text{If I get a score of }4,\text{it counts as }0\text{ points}$$
$$\text{If I get a score of }0, 1, 2,\text{or }3,\text{it counts as }-100\text{ points}$$

In order to figure out my score, I divide my total points by number of responses.

So, if I had four scores of $5$, one $4$, and a $3$, I would have a score of:

$$\frac{(4\cdot 100)+(1\cdot 0)+(1\cdot -100)}{6}=50$$

I need an equation (or system of equations) that I can use in order to figure out how many scores of $5$ I need (potentially with a combination of the other scores) to get to a certain employee score. For example, how many scores of $5$ do I need to achieve an employee score of $80$ if I get a score of $4$ as well as two scores of $0, 1, 2,$ or $3$?

Comment: Say you get $n_+$ scores of 5, $n_0$ scores of 4, and $n_-$ scores of 0,1,2,3. Then employee score E is $$E(n_++n_-+n_0)=100(n_+-n_-)$$To see how many $5$'s you need to equal 80, you have $$0.8(n_++n_-+n_0)=n_+-n_-\\0.8n_0+1.8n_-=0.2n_+$$ From here, choose $n_-$ and $n_0$ however you wish.